# Non Linear Differential Equation Asymptotics

Tags: nonlinear, asymptotics

I wish to study the asymptotic behaviour of the following equation:

$\frac{d^2 a}{dr^2} = 2 a(r) \phi(r)^2 + B_1 a(r) (1-\phi^2(r) + B_2 a(r)^2)$

$\phi(r)\longrightarrow 1$ as $r\longrightarrow \infty$

Hence my equation boils down to:

$\frac{d^2 a}{dr^2} = 2 a(r) + A a(r)^3$
where I define $A=B_1B_2$.

This should have to solutions. I wish to get both the possible solutions since I'm interested in studying the divergent solution as well. The boundary conditions are not fixed and I wish to study the most general solution. With this context , I have the following two related questions:

1. If I wish to get the divergent solution, then $a^3$ would be leading and $a$ would be subleading and my equation looks like:

$\frac{d^2 a}{dr^2} = A a(r)^3$

It is clear that this equation has $\sqrt{\frac{2}{A}} \frac{1}{r}$ as one solution. However, I tried solving this in Mathematica

```
DSolve[a''[r] -  A  a [r]^3 == 0, a[r], r]
```

and Mathematica gave the error:[image] followed by the answer in terms of JacobiSN functions.

```
{{a[r] -> -((
    2^(1/4) Sqrt[(I Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[C[1]]] Sqrt[C[1]]
      JacobiSN[((-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[A] r^2 Sqrt[C[1]] + 
        2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[A] r Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] + 
        Sqrt[2] Sqrt[A] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2]^2])/Sqrt[2], -1])/Sqrt[
    A])}, {a[r] -> (
   2^(1/4) Sqrt[(I Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[C[1]]] Sqrt[C[1]]
     JacobiSN[((-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[
      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[A] r^2 Sqrt[C[1]] + 
       2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[A] r Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[A] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2]^2])/Sqrt[2], -1])/Sqrt[A]}}
```

$\sqrt{\frac{2}{A}} \frac{1}{r}$ is not apparent amongst the solutions Mathematica gives.

So I'm not sure why I'm getting an error and how to successfully manipulate this hiccup.

2. My second question is regarding solving the original equation as a whole and not ignoring any terms :

$\frac{d^2 a}{dr^2} = 2 a(r) + A a(r)^3$

I did the following :

```
DSolve[a''[r] - 2 a[r] -  A  a [r]^3 == 0, a[r], r]
```

and I got the following answer:

```
Solve[-(((2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 A C[1]]) (1 - (
      A a[r]^2)/(-2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 A C[1]])) (2 + (2 A a[r]^2)/(
      2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 A C[1]])) EllipticF[
     I ArcSinh[a[r] Sqrt[A/(2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 A C[1]])]], -((
      2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 A C[1]])/(-2 + Sqrt[4 - 2 A C[1]]))]^2)/(
   A (4 a[r]^2 + A a[r]^4 + 2 C[1]))) == (r + C[2])^2, a[r]]
```

This is also a bit unhelpful. Since I'm interested in the asymptotics I also tried AsymptoticDSolveValue in the following manner:

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[a''[r] - 2  a[r] - A^2  a[r]^3 == 0, 
 a[r], {r, \[Infinity], 4}]
```

However, Mathematica just gave me back the input command with the equation rearranged.

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[-2 a[r] - 
   A^2 a[r]^3 + (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] == 0, 
 a[r], {r, \[Infinity], 4}]
```

Any suggestions in solving these issues or getting the asymptotics for the equation in question 2, by some other method which could possibly be better suited would be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the "boiled" equation should be `a''[r]==2 a[r]+B2 a[r]^2`!

Comment: @Ulrich the term inside the bracket is $(1-\phi^2(r) + B_2 a^2(r))$, so at infinity we get $Aa(r)^3$

Comment: Thanks, my fault (bracket...)

Comment: `DSolve[a''[r] - 2 a[r] -  A  a [r]^3 == 0, a[r], r]`  gives an implicit solution  `r=f[ a]`, which might be helpful. Looking at the ode I would expect stationary `r->Infinity`solution `a[r]->0&&a[r]->-2/A `